# Looking for bitcoin and other cryptocurrency intraday prices

Tags: raw-data, historical-trade-data

I've come across some datasets that include every trade made but I'm just looking for the price of bitcoin at a high frequency. Every minute would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Using [bfxdata.com](https://www.bfxdata.com/datadownload/) which looks at Bitfinex stats, the largest in volume Bitcoin exchange currently, can help you out.

In the link above it allows you to download tons of different types of data in csv format, and from the website you can look up and find tons of information. Be advised, please do not systematically download or set up a bot auto-downloading the csv files, you will be blocked.

And yes that includes all transaction stats since "2013-04-01 02:00:00", but it's updated hourly not by minute. (that would be almost too much data to handle anyway)

[Bitfinex](https://www.bitfinex.com/trade_history/BTCUSD) also has stuff you can look at, but it doesn't say the price every minute, it just shows all trade history. You can download information with a max of a three month range per time.

Hope this helps.

Happy Bitcoining